# Perfectly matchable edges in a bipartite graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-algorithms, matching

Consider the following problem:

Given a bipartite graph $G = (V, E)$, an unmatched edge is one that does not appear in any perfect matching. Design an algorithm to find all unmatched edges. (assume |V| = n and |E| = m)

There is an $O(m + T(m, n))$ algorithm to solve this problem [1, Web exercise 36]. Where $T(m, n)$ is the time complexity of the best algorithm for finding perfect matching in a bipartite graph $G$. I want to get a reference to the research paper/work where the algorithm was proposed, for citation.

[1] http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/

Comment: I claim no originality for this idea, but as long as you're collecting web references, I have a blog post at http://11011110.livejournal.com/335.html from 2005 that describes it.

Comment: @DavidEppstein Thanks for the web reference. I was also interested in a paper that I can cite in my work.

Comment: @DavidEppstein The link to your Blog is broken? Please fix it.

Comment: Now at https://11011110.github.io/blog/2005/07/20/updated-python-library.html (I moved my blog there last April. This is the first post I made to it at the old location!)

Answer (score 1):

It's a consequence of [Dulmage-Mendelsohn decompositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulmage%E2%80%93Mendelsohn_decomposition).

Comment: Can you point to the section/page number which contains the relevant theorem ?

Comment: I gave a link in my answer, so please follow that link and find a relevant reference there.